# What photographer took this mid 20th-century color photograph?

Tags: art, photographer, artistic

Can anyone please identify who is the photographer of this picture and what is the name of the picture?

It appears taken in middle of 20th century (1950s?) in a rural place. It looks like summer. A young blonde girl is lying naked on a chair, in front of a window. Outside the window there is a yellow field and in the back, after the field, there is a man standing next to a blue car. The style is painting-like, and it's hard to tell if it's even really a photograph in the low-quality jpeg image I've found.

This is the photograph, which may not be "workplace safe", as it contains some nudity: http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5558/pic025v.jpg

Comment: Can some of the people voting to close this indicate why? This _is_ a photography QA site, [not just a "camera club"](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-to-move-from-a-camera-club-to-a-photography-club).

Comment: @mattdm haven't voted myself, but I can see that the question _is_ on borderline of image recognition, which is generally considered off topic (even by yourself) - see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/is-it-ok-to-post-a-picture-of-an-insect-to-ask-what-it-is

Comment: @Imre: there's a huge difference between _what is this photograph in art history_ and _what is this bug I took a picture of_?

Comment: @mattdm - Personally, I think its too localized - and thats how I voted.  I don't think its offtopic.  I think its unlikely another user would ever be able to find the question - even in the incredibly unlikely event that they had the exact same question. There was some chat discussion.

Comment: Someone might find it from the textual description. It's not a completely one-off question, as evidenced by the fact that there _do_ exist web pages which talk about the photo. If the answer had been "It's Ansel Adams' _Moon Over Half Dome_!", where would you come down? And where do you draw that line? I guess this is something for meta...

Comment: @mattdm - Btw in regards to this - http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/what-is-the-point-of-help-me-remember-this-game-questions JeffAtwood - "or 'help me identify this {thing}' questions should be banned from all sites as a matter of policy"

Comment: @rfusca: Read further — "if the user can produce a screenshot or some other reasonably concrete identifying artifact to work with, other than 'I kinda remember..' I have less objections to these questions." This is different because here the image _is_ the thing (if reproduced poorly); it's not "vague, broad, half-remembered descriptions".

Comment: @mattdm - prior to that "is because these questions are insubstantial -- based on vague, broad, half-remembered descriptions (and possibly **at best a screenshot**) -- it is unlikely anyone else will be able to find them through a web search. **That does not advance our goal to make the internet better.**"  I just don't think anybody would ever find this question if they had the same one.  If we want to continue this conversation though, I'd suggest chat.

Comment: I do agree that as far as these kinds of questions go, this is *as good as it probably gets* though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because, while I strongly believe it was on topic when asked, the link is now dead, making it pretty much useless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just do an image search with google on that url

http://www.google.com/imghp

and it will offer to search by image.

Which results in:

> Best guess for this image: [Saul Leiter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_Leiter)

and, following some of the results, the title "Lanesville, 1958".

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that google images could do reverse image search. I tried http://www.tineye.com for that but with no result. Thanks again!